# Ajax PHP Response login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a response through my `login.js` and my `logindata.php` via my `login.php`, however I always seem to get the error message `Something went wrong! Try again.` (my own custom message in `login.js`) even though I write in the correct login details

login.php

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" autocomplete="off">   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="12" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="12" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" required/>
    </div>
    <input id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Login"/>
    <a href="/register" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Register</a>
</form>
```

login.js

```
$(function () {
    var action = '';
    var form_data = '';
    $('#login').click(function () {
        action = $("#loginform").attr("action");
        form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            is_ajax: '1'
        };
        $('#login').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) { //Enter key pressed
                $('#login').click();
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'logindata.php',
            data: form_data,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 'success') {
                    $("#loginform").slideUp('slow', function () {
                        $("#message").html('<script>location.reload();</script><div class=\"alert alert-success\">Logged in. Reloading...</div>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#message').hide().html("<br/><div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Something went wrong! Try again.</div>").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

logindata.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    header("Location: /home")
}
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    header("Location: /home")
} else {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","maplexeno");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from accounts WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $username;
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "false";
    }

    session_start();
}
?>
```

Comment: Well ye, that tends to happen if you echo "true" or "false" while expecting "succes"..

Comment: I've already tried making echo "success", however that didn't work either

Comment: Well at least change that in the code. It's not gonna work like this no matter what. Change "true" to "success" or everyone here will tell you the same.

Comment: You have this line in your code already `console.log(response);`.  What is actually being logged to the console?  (But also what icecub said ;P)

Comment: change it if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $username;
        return "success";exit();
    } else {
        return "false";exit();
    }

Comment: did you tried what i said?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh That didn't seem to work

Comment: Try using @anantkumarsingh code but use `echo` instead of `return`. I'm not 100% sure but I believe return doesn't work in an ajax response.

Comment: Did you tried my code by changing what @icecub said?

Comment: Yes I did, it didn't work

Comment: You can't put `session_start()` at the bottom of your script. it has to be at the VERY top, right after `<?php`

Comment: Also, change your query to `SELECT * from accounts WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}'"` Don't use `LIKE` when authenticating somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably receiving an header output, or `session_start()` error in your log. You have to put `session_start()` at the very top of your `logindata.php` script, right after `<?php` and before anything else.

```
<?php
session_start();

// rest of your code...
```

You can try doing the following in login.js to see what PHP errors are being generated without having to go to your log file.

```
success: function (response) {
alert(response);
```

This should help you track down the issue if it's not `session_start()`

Comment: alert(response); sent me an alert of the html source

Comment: I'm looking through the code and you have a lot of issues, not only missing semi-colons here and there but just the general logic of it all is weird. I'm too tired to help right now, but if you don't get this resolved by tomorrow I'll help you fix it.

Comment: If my answer helped solve it, please mark it as answered to close this thread and prevent others from attempting to help. Thanks. :)

Comment: It didn't though, I fixed it by myself in the end ^^

Comment: Was it related to what you posted here? If so maybe you could answer the question yourself so others may learn from it?